# Regular expression searching for content in a section or block of text in a file

Tags: regex, linux, devops

I have a file, with sections of content as following. I need to search for portnumbers under each section of content seperately .

path: etc/a.Config file

```
 Global
  user abc
  group aaa

 frontend one
  bind 10.1.0.15:80
  option tcp

 frontend two
  bind 10.1.1.25:666
  option tcp 

 frontend three 
  bind 10.2.2.45:444
  option tcp
```

output should be:

```
  frontend one port: 80
  frontend two port: 666
  frontend three port: 444
```

what would be complete regular expresion as I need to search for portnumbers under each section of text  seperately from same file. The searching is done for pattern of content in config file, but im writing the code in ruby file as its needed by puppet, does it make any difference for regex if its in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that does the matching ... how to apply that to the entire file I leave up to you ;)

```
$ cat a
#!/usr/bin/ruby

text = " Global
  user abc
  group aaa

 frontend one
  bind 10.1.0.15:80
  option tcp
"
m = text.match /(frontend [^ ]+)\n.*bind [^:]+:([0-9]+)/
puts "#{m[1]} port: #{m[2]}"

$ ./a
frontend one port: 80
```

Explanatory words:

```
/  # the slashes start and terminate the regex
(  # start a capturing group, capturing subexpressions matching the following line
frontend [^ ]+  # a literal frontend followed by a space followed by at least one non-space
)  # close capturing group
\n.*  # match new line, followed by any number of any character  
bind [^:]+:  #  match the word bind followed by a space followed by at least one non-colon followed by a colon
(
[0-9]+  # captured digits, one at the least
)
/
# m is an array that holds captured results from above.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, can you please give a explanation of the terms used in expression, to come up with output : frontend one port: 80 . i m trying to do in my serverspec ruby file in puppet.

Comment: Sure ... does that suffice?

Comment: Thanks very much my question was actually on server spec file. The port must be included as part of "it should contain" . Do you have any idea. Its not that i have to execute and get which port number it has. But i have to mention that port number is related to this section . Do you have any idea on the server spec in puppet.